# Unable to invoke a recursive function with AWS Lambda

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, aws-sdk-nodejs

I am unable to call a Lambda Function recursively. My functions are within the same VPC, they are able to communicate to my RDS resources. They are also able to reach out public resources thanks to the NAT Gateway. I am able to successfully invoke a function once from my task manager (see below). The historical function should run recursively until criteria has been met, it invokes it self but nothing happens.

I'm working on a project that has a task manager that runs on a cron as a lambda function. Currently, the function searches a MySQL database hosted via RDS for any tasks that are not yet started or completed. It then compiles the params necessary and calls another lambda function to actually do the lifting.

Task Code:

```
module.exports.tasks = async (event, context) => {
let tasks = await getTasks();

  let tasksStarted = 0;

  for (const task of tasks) {
    let attr1 = await redacted;
    let attr2 = await redacted;

    let body = {
      task: task,
      account: attr1,
      pair: attr2
    };

    const params = {
      FunctionName: "redcated-historical",
      InvocationType: "Event",
      Payload: JSON.stringify(body)
    };
    tasksStarted += 1;
    console.log("LAMBDA Invoke");
    lambda.invoke(params, context.done);
    console.log("Updating DB");
    let update = await updateTask(task.id, {
      start_date: new Date()
    });
    console.log("Updated")
  }
  console.log("Finished Starting Tasks");

  await mysql.end();

  // Return the results
  return {
    tasksStarted: tasksStarted
  };
};
```

Recursive Code (This code doesn't work):

```
module.exports.historicalTask = async (event, context) => {
  console.log("STARTING HISTORICAL TASK");

  api.configure({
    apiKey: event.account.api_token,
    accountId: event.account.account_id
  });

  console.log("Getting objects from API");

  const {objects, params} = await api.call(event.task)

  let lastTimeStamp = objects[objects.length - 1].time;
  let promises = [];
  console.log("Starting Save");
  for (let object of objects) {
    let history = new Historical();
    history.timestamp = new Date(object.time);
    //redacted info
    promises.push(history.insert(mysql));
  }
  console.log("WAITING FOR SAVE");
  const result = await Promise.all(promises);
  console.log("SAVED");
  let newDate = moment(lastTimeStamp);
  let endDate = moment(event.task['search_end_date']);

  newDate.add(5, 'm');

  if (newDate.isAfter(endDate)) {
    await updateTask(event.task.id, {
      completed: 1,
      completed_date: new Date()
    });
    await mysql.end();
    context.done('Finished');
  } else {
    event.task.search_start_date = newDate.toDate();
    const params = {
      FunctionName: "redacted-historical",
      InvocationType: "Event",
      Payload: JSON.stringify(event)
    };
    await updateTask()
    console.log("Invoking again!");
    lambda.invoke(params, context.done);
  }
};
```

My expected result is that the redacted-historical function would continue to invoke itself until the criteria (included) is met. Am I missing something? I've seen multiple articles and examples with recursive Lambda functions.

I'm assuming it's not my roles, or VPC which I have seen as common issues as I'm able to invoke the function once?

Comment: Don't use recursive functions in production unless you _absolutely_ have to. If it's a well behaved recursion, you can write it as a normal while loop. If it's unknown behaviour recursion, that's your signal right there that this is not the code you should be using.

Comment: Thanks! Thinking about it I could restructure the cron job to start the task again and nix the recursion idea entirely.

Comment: as long as you remember to have your cron job check for the last job's result: if an error occurs in a job, that error has to be recorded somewhere, so you don't just keep running guaranteed-to-fail jobs just because there's no human pressing the "go" button.

Comment: Agree with @Mike's assessment, but the problem here seems to be the mixing of an async handler and context.done and SDK calls that use callbacks.  If you're going to use an async handler function, I don't *think* you have the option of reverting to the context callbacks.  Your handler needs to return a promise or await everything asynchronous that it does.