# Recursive function call fails to recurse in AWS Lambda - Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, recursion, aws-lambda

Im trying to replace python dictionary key with a different key name recursively for which i am using aws lambda with a api endpoint to trigger.
Suprisingly the recursion part fails for weird reason. The same code works fine in local.

Checked cloudwatch logs. No error message get displayed there. Let me know if im missing anything here

EDIT: Related to [Unable to invoke a recursive function with AWS Lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54374550/unable-to-invoke-a-recursive-function-with-aws-lambda) and [recursive lambda function never seems to run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58035172/recursive-lambda-function-never-seems-to-run)

```
### function that is called inside lambda_handler

def replace_recursive(data,mapping):
    for dict1 in data:
        for k,v in dict1.copy().items():
            if isinstance(v,dict):
                dict1[k] = replace_recursive([v], mapping)
            try:
                dict1[mapping['value'][mapping['key'].index(k)]] = dict1.pop(mapping['key'][mapping['key'].index(k)])
            except KeyError:
                continue
    return data
```

```
## lambda handler

def lambda_handler(events,_):
    resp = {'statusCode': 200}
    parsed_events = json.loads(events['body'])
    if parsed_events:
        op = replace_recursive(parsed_events,schema)
        resp['body'] = json.dumps(op)
    return resp
```

Input I pass:

```
{
  "name": "michael",
  "age": 35,
  "family": {
    "name": "john",
    "relation": "father"
  }
}
```

In the output, keys in the nested dictionary are not getting updated. Only outer keys get modified

Comment: Never use a bare `try: except: ...` without a clear exception type - as you've noticed, you can never tell what goes wrong.

Comment: Fails how? What's the error?

Comment: Also, you aren't showing what `mapping` (i.e. `schema`) is, so it's a bit hard to help.

Comment: Furthermore, this will simply _not work_ with the body you're passing (if that's what you put in `events["body"]`, since looping over a dict (in `for dict1 in data`) would loop over the keys.

Comment: @AKX Reason i put in a bare try...except.. is every time I update a key with a new key, Python adds the new key to the end of the dict and since im inside a for loop, new keys get fed into the for loop and throws a keyError

Comment: Just to clarify: I dont get any error running the above code. It just doesnot replace the nested dictionary keys

Comment: There is _never_ a reason to put in a bare try-except. If you're looking for KeyErrors, `except KeyError:`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're ingesting JSON, you can do the key replacement right in the parse phase for a faster and simpler experience using the `object_pairs_hook` argument to `json.loads`.

```
import json

key_mapping = {
    "name": "noot",
    "age": "doot",
    "relation": "root",
}


def lambda_handler(events, _):
    replaced_events = json.loads(
        events["body"],
        object_pairs_hook=lambda pairs: dict(
            (key_mapping.get(k, k), v) for k, v in pairs
        ),
    )
    return {
        "statusCode": 200,
        "body": json.dumps(replaced_events),
    }


body = {
    "name": "michael",
    "age": 35,
    "family": {"name": "john", "relation": "father"},
}
print(
    lambda_handler(
        {
            "body": json.dumps(body),
        },
        None,
    )
)
```

prints out

```
{'statusCode': 200, 'body': '{"noot": "michael", "doot": 35, "family": {"noot": "john", "root": "father"}}'}
```

Comment: Thanks.. never heard of object_pairs_hook. Im trying this

Comment: Works fine inside AWS lambda. Thanks.
Any idea why recursive code doesnt work inside AWS lambda? or am I making a mistake?

Comment: As I mentioned in the original comments, your original code simply didn't work at all.